# Google smart home Actions on Google Simulator not working

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I create a smart home action regarding to https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create

but when I want to test it in simulater, go below error

> Sorry, this action is not available for your app. In the simulator,
>   you are only able to invoke actions that you have added to your app.
>   For more information on how to invoke your app, click here
>   https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hwQL.png)

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Testing and Publishing](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/testing-deploying) section of the documentation, you need to first do account linking through the Google Assistant application on your phone. That associates your Google account, and your Google Assistant, with an account on your smart home server. Once that happens, you should be able to use the simulator to make authenticated requests. Before that happens, there's no association and so a request cannot be made.

It should also be mentioned that the way to invoke and use smart home actions is different from a standard conversational action. With a conversational action, you may enter into the simulator "Talk to Number Genie" to invoke your action. With smart home actions, commands are given as one-off queries. There is no "talk to my smart light". You instead will be able to directly enter "turn on my light".